# Assign object property to value if x = null

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have an Ember computed property that creates an object from an ember model.

In one of the object properties I am trying to evaluate whether an ID exists and in cases where it does not make the property 0 rather than null.

The computed property is as follows:

```
SpecSortData: computed('customerfr', function() {
  let newArray = [];
  this.get('customerfr').forEach(function(x) {

    function idCheck() {
      if (x.data.speciality_id !== null) {
        return x.data.specialty_id
      } else {
        return 0
      }
    };

    let newData = {
      specialtyID: x.data.specialty_id,
      specialty: x.data.specialty_name,
      customerID: x.data.customer_id,
      tspecID: idCheck()
    }
    newArray.push(newData)
  })
  return newArray
}),
```

I haven't been able to get the idCheck() function to evaluate properly. The specialty_id field is either a number or null. In cases where it is a number, I would like tspecID to be that number. In cases where it is null I would like tspecID to be 0.

The above function currently adds the speciality_id number to the tspecID property but it does not handle the null cases, they remain as null. If I invert the condition I get all tspecID properties set to 0.

I have tried a few variations of the condition and always end up with either:

- specID = specialtyID with null cases remaining null
- tspecID = always 0

I feel like I am making a basic error in the evaluation or function construction but I am stumped.

Comment: You could simply use `Number(x.data.specialty_id)`, but I don't see why your current code wouldn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a [logical OR `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_()) and take zero if `speciality_id` is falsy.

BTW, `speciality_id !== specialty_id`.

```
function idCheck() {
    return x.data.speciality_id || 0;
}
```

Comment: Oh wow, that didn't even occur to me. I'm a newbie and stumbling my way through but I can already see a few different applications of that type of logic in my app. In 5 lines you just taught me a new way to evaluate, thank you very much!